# Appeal question which is onhold?

Tags: support, on-hold

What is the correct process to follow to appeal a question which is on hold after the question has been edited?

The reason I ask is I have edited a question and this edit was approved however the question is still on hold. I do not see the logic of approving an edit but leaving a question on hold.

Appreciate clarification on how this works.

Comment: See also [the help topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/reopen-questions)

Comment: So I have read possible duplicate and I don't see my question being the same.  My edit to the question was approved but the question is still on hold?

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan Thanks I will flag it but I still think the process is confusing.  Surely an approved edit to an on hold question should re-open it?

Comment: @bated Your edit goes to a reopen queue where it is voted on. There is no guarantee that it will be reopened, just a guarantee that it will be shown to a few users to vote on. If they decide it isn't worth opening then it will stay closed unless 5 users with > 3k rep find it naturally and vote to reopen it. All of this is explained in the post ryanyuyu mentioned as well as the help topic Mike mentioned.

Comment: [Here is the review task for the question in question](http://stackoverflow.com/review/reopen/9664606). It has so far received one reopen vote and no leave closed votes. Personally I would have voted to leave it closed (if I hadn't already spent all of my leave closed votes for the day) as your new version is too broad for Stack Overflow. See also: [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users)

Comment: A better question might be: why did you waste your time (and that of those that had to review your edit, and now all of ours on Meta) editing that question?

Comment: The review has been completed as "Leave Closed". Now the only way it will get reopened is if four more users find your question naturally and are convinced that it shouldn't be closed.

Comment: @jonrsharpe because it is something which is used frequently in Oracle ATG.

Comment: @bated so what? That doesn't make SO a code-writing or tutorial service.

Comment: Contrary to popular belief Stack Overflow is not a code-writing or help-desk service. It is not a place for every possible question that every possible programmer could ever possibly have. Stack Overflow's purpose is to create a repository of useful solutions to common programming problems faced by programmers everywhere. A question asker getting an answer to their question is a side-effect. Despite the fact that there are thousands of users answering low quality questions, there is a quality standard that should be adhered to. Please read the relevent help center docs, FAQ and take the tour.

Comment: Ok, so clearly the SO gods have spoken.  Nobody appears to recognize how idiotic it is to have an edit to an on hold question approved but for the question to remain on hold? Note to self: never challenge the status quo. Keep on keeping on.

Comment: @bated they are two **completely separate** processes - reviewers looking at suggested edits are just checking whether the edit has improved the post at all (this queue is available at 2,000 rep), whereas reviewers looking at reopen are trying to determine whether the question is now on-topic (this requires 3,000+ rep). Edited questions aren't necessarily on-hold, and questions in the reopen queue haven't necessarily been edited. *"Your edit improved the question"* is not the same as *"this question is now on-topic"*, nor should it be.

Comment: @jonrsharpe really???  You think that it is a **logical** flow to edit a question and have it approved but leave it on hold?

Comment: Yes, I really do. Again, they are separate things; conflating the two would only lead to confusion and edge cases. The reviews have concluded that: 1. Your edit improved the question; but 2. It was not sufficient for the question to be reopened. This has already taken far more of everybody's time than the question was ever worth, so I'll leave it there.

Comment: @bated If people in the edit review queue were more reliable, I'd agree with you. The problem is that someone can just capitalize a terrible question, fix some formatting, and it will most likely be approved. If such an edit is approved, why should the question get reopened? If you believe that we need a new queue for "edited on hold questions that should be reopened should the edit get approved", that sounds like a Feature Request. Feel free to open a new post with a Feature request tag and defend that point there. Be careful, it might not be an easy one to defend though